# Match last occurency only when several

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string:
`"http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm"`

I then try to match 63582484:
`"http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm".match(/\d{8}/)`

But then I get the answer `20170401`. 
How do I change `match` to only match the last occurency of 8 digits?

Comment: `.match(/(\d{8})\.htm/)[1]`

Comment: If your string contains a newline, `/\d{8}(?!.*\d+)/` might return unexpected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use global flag (`g`), and get the last one:

```
var matches = "http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm".match(/\d{8}/g);
matches[matches.length - 1]  // => "63582484"
```

Comment: @falsetrue This solution works better. Sometimrs the other one does not find any occurencies.

Comment: @user1665355: Note that this one only matches 8 consecutive digits without checking any boundaries. That means, you will get `09876543` from `some words 1234567890 0987654321` using [this solution](https://regex101.com/r/aB2pY2/1), while you will get the last 8 digits `87654321` with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/aB2pY2/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I think using word boundary is more easier to use: `\d{8}\b`

Comment: But you still have to get all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

```js
console.log("http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm".match(/\d{8}(?!.*\d{8})/)[0]);
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fM8vU1/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**UPDATE :**

If the string always in specific format(which is followed by `.htm` ) then you can use regex `\d{8})\.htm/` as suggested by [@Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar)

```js
console.log("http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm".match(/(\d{8})\.htm/)[1]);
```

or you can use the same by positive look ahead, in this case there is no need of captured group

```js
console.log("http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm".match(/\d{8}(?=\.htm)/)[0]);
```

Comment: @Pravan C Balan Ok then I get always the last occurency?

Comment: This answer does not address the original question, namely, it will not always return the last eight digits in a string.

Comment: Sure: `var s = "Line 12345678 - 87654321 end\nLine 2: 09876543 : 26543897 end of string";`. My answer shows how to do that correctly with the shortest possible pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : ok , i don't think he needs to get from that much complex string.... even though your solution will fails if a digit after the 8 digit , for eg : `abc 12345678 fdfd 5`.... , i this case it will not match anything

Comment: You can also do a greedy match-all, followed by 8 consecutive digits: `"http://www.website.com/20170401_63582484.htm".match(/.*(\d{8})/)[1]`

Comment: I have updated my answer with two solutions that match any last eight digits that are not followed by any other eight digit sequences.

Answer (score 1):

To match the last 8 digits in a whole string that might contain newline symbols, use

```
/\d{8}(?=(?:(?!\d{8})[\s\S])*$)/
```

The `(?=(?:(?!\d{8})[\s\S])*$)` is positive lookahead that requires the string to have no other eight digit chunks up to the end of the string. The `[\s\S]` pattern matches any character including a newline and the enclosed negative lookahead `(?!\d{8})` *tempers* this generic character class.

**Alternative 1**: An identical result can be achieved with a negative  lookahead:

```
/\d{8}(?![\s\S]*\d{8}[\s\S]*$)/
```

**Alternative 2**: To match the last 8 consecutive digits in a string *that has no more other numbers after it* you can use a regex with a `(?=\D*$)` positive lookahead:

```
/\d{8}(?=\D*$)/
```

The lookahead requires that the eight digits must be followed by zero or more non-digit characters up to the end of the string.

Use it like

```
var m = str.match(/\d{8}(?=\D*$)/);
if (m) { 
    document.body.innerHTML = m[0];
}
```

Comment: I think it depends on the input, which solution to be preferred. If input always contains `.htm` I would prefer the positive lookahead, else yours.